# How to bind ListView Control in Windows App Store with Design Time Data without using a View Model through ItemsSource property

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to bind ListView to design time data so that I can work with it from Blend and I have succeeded using this approach. I create a ViewModel class and in its Constructor I load design time data. This data is returned through a property in the ViewModel (This property returns a list object which is populated in the constructor). Then in the XAML I Create a CollectionViewSource like this

```
<CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="PersonSource"
            Source="{Binding Persons}"
            d:Source="{Binding Persons, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=local:PersonViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

In  my ListView all that I have to do now is this

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstPatients" Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonSource}}">
```

This works fine but my question is what if I don't want to use a ViewModel and its property in the collectionViewSource. We have the option of setting the ItemsSource in the code behind and what If I want to use that approach? In the above example I have to tell the property of the ViewModel in {Binding Persons} and the ViewModel class in the Type=local:PersonViewModel and I want to skip both of these and simply set the ItemsSource property somehow at design time.

Comment: why you want that it is a good approach but if you want to you can set the itemsource from the code behind but for design the way you done is the best one .

Comment: Actually I was thinking that sometime I might not want to use a ViewModel, in that case I was hoping there is some other way...

Comment: viewmodels are basically where your properties are defined and if you want to you can define these properties in any other class in that case you have just give the right path of your properties.And  viewmodels are just for the convenience.

Comment: Yes Guys I totally understand your point that using view model is more convinent and probably the best way to go, but I still want to know if the other way around is possible? I don't want to argue the us of VMs rather just find a way that will work without them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blend can do it. Too much to type here, but as of VS 2013, it's built-in.

What you are talking about is a combination of Design and Sample data.

Here's the step-by-step: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Content/ViewContent.aspx?et=5695&m=5692&ct=23173#?fbid=_ddIepu0_zE

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Jerry for the reply. Guess VS 2013 is the way to go then.